# Cannot move files in spring without breaking project

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to communicate between the frontend and backend of a project using spring, Java and html for the frontend.

I've put in the code from https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ into my work in an attempt to figure out what I needed to do.

I have two issues. The first is that I want to make it so that I can separate the controllers and domains into separate folders to make it neater but when I do that, spring doesn't load properly and gives a 500 or 405 error if you attempt to submit anything, saying that the "POST" method isn't allowed. If I move the files outside of the separate folders and in with the "application" it appears to work fine and does its job properly. I've also noticed that if the files are in separate folders then the website only appears if you add the "html" extension to the end of the web address, e.g. "`localhost:8080/greeting.html`" and if they are out of the folders they only appear if you don't use the extension.

[This is the configuration that works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyh75.png)

This brings me to my second issue. I cannot move my spring files in my repo without breaking the application to the point that I have to re-download my latest revision from git. Even attempting to move the files back after moving them still causes the issue.

Why does it still claim there's now two copies?

This is the error code:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class [com.ess.employee.EmployeeApplication];
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
>   Annotation-specified bean name 'greetingController' for bean class
>   [com.ess.employee.GreetingController] conflicts with existing,
>   non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
>   [com.ess.employee.controllers.GreetingController]

Please suggest.

Comment: You didn't post any code, but this sounds like you most likely just didn't keep the classes in packages where `@ComponentScan` would find them. Read the documentation on where that starts looking and how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, we see that GreetingController Class is in two places.

As per error, its in com.ess.employee.controllers.GreetingController (inside controllers folder)

As per image, its in com.ess.employee.GreetingController (outside controllers folder)

It may be due to build issues. Do a clean build. Stale files will be removed. And then lets hope for the best!